# multiple choice summation problem

Tags: calculus

> Let
>   $$X = \frac{1}{1001} + \frac{1}{1002} + \frac{1}{1003} + \cdots + \frac{1}{3001}.$$
>   Then
>
> (A) $X < 1$
>
> (B) $X > 3/2$
>
> (C) $1 < X < 3/2$
>
> (D) none of the above holds.

I assume that the answer is the third choice $1<X<3/2$. I integrate out $1/x$ in the interval $(1001, 3001)$ and get a result that satisfies only the choice C. Is this a Riemann sum? Please help.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, your Riemann sum idea was correct, and $X\approx \log 3$ so the correct option was indeed C).

Comment: @RagibZaman thank you but can you please explain why this discrete sum is integrated

Comment: @Ranabir: You can think of the sum as the integral of a step function. When you switch to integrating $1/x$ instead, you introduce a vertical error that is never more than the difference between two neighboring terms, which is about $10^{-6}$ at the most. So a conservative estimate of the _total_ error is $10^{-6}$ times the width of the integrated area -- concretely, the integral will be at most 0.002 from the true sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to your Riemann sum approach: the idea is that for positive, decreasing functions, the Riemann sum and the integral [carefully approximate each other](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx), more or less as in the proof of the integral test of convergence.

If you'd like another sort of approach, we could approach it naively. Separate the sum into $250$ element blocks, $\frac{1}{1001}$ to $\frac{1}{1250}$ in the first block $B_1$, $\frac{1}{1251}$ to $\frac{1}{1500}$ in the second block $B_2$, and so on. We'll have $12$ blocks.

Note that $\frac{1}{5} = \frac{250}{1250} \leq B_1 \leq \frac{250}{1000} = \frac{1}{4}$. Similarly, we get that $\frac{1}{i + 4} \leq B_i \leq \frac{1}{i+3}$ for all of our blocks.

This means that our sum has upper and lower bounds:

$$ 1 < \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \dots \frac{1}{16} \leq B_1 + \dots + B_{12} \leq \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{15}< \frac{3}{2}$$

And this gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It is approximately $\int_{1000}^{3000}dt/t = \log(3)$.

To explain why the Riemann Sum is close you should think about the approximating rectangles and the actual curve of $x \mapsto 1/x$. Since the curvature is nearly zero, the approximation will be  very close.